# Applet being blocked by Java settings

Tags: java, security, applet

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/getStarted.html) is an "Hello World" applet is given on Oracle's it works online. Oracle has also provided these tutorial as offline version. In download files of same website applets are not working rather these are being blocked by Java setting. There was also message that I can change security settings from Java Control Panel. I changed settings from `high` to `medium` but applet is sill being blocked by Java.

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: I found chapters in "Java How to Program (9th Edition) - Harvey Deitel" so started working on it.

Comment: Put applets aside and concentrate on applications.

Answer (score 0):

- Click on the Start button and then click on the Control Panel option.
- In the Control Panel Search enter Java Control Panel.
- Click on the Java icon to open the Java Control Panel.

  1. In the Java Control Panel, under the General tab, click Settings under the Temporary Internet Files section. The Temporary Files Settings dialog box appears.
  2. Click Delete Files on the Temporary Files Settings dialog. The Delete Files and Applications dialog box appears.
  3. Click OK on the Delete Files and Applications dialog. This deletes all the Downloaded Applications and Applets from the cache.
  4. Click OK on the Temporary Files Settings dialog. If you want to delete a specific application and applet from the cache, click on View Application and View Applet options respectively.

Now try to run your applet again and it should work.